# Spring : autowiring inside non spring class

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I have this HTTP listener subclass

```
public class MigificSessionListener implements HttpSessionListener {
    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("notificationThread")
    private NotificationThread notificationThread;  

    @Override
    public void sessionDestroyed(HttpSessionEvent hse) {
          // here notificationThread value is null
    }
}
```

Value of `notificationThread` inside `sessionDestroyed()` is `null`.

How can i autowire `sessionDestroyed` inside this class ?

Comment: LMGTFY ;)
http://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-how-to-do-dependency-injection-in-your-session-listener/

ContextLoaderListener - and to autowire You have to simply use "<context:annotation-config />"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `MigificSessionListener` in not in your spring conext, spring even do not know it exists.
You can use `WebApplicationContextUtils` to get your spring context from `ServletContext`

`WebApplicationContextUtils.getWebApplicationContext(sessionEvent.getSession().getServletContext())`

Answer (score 0):

Convert your non-Spring managed class `MigificSessionListener` into a Spring-managed one by annotating it with [@Configurable](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/annotation/Configurable.html).

For this annotation to be recognised you need `<context:spring-configured/>` in your Spring XML config or `@EnableSpringConfigured` if you are using Spring Java config.

The `@Autowired` or injection of other dependencies will then succeed.

Comment: it didn't work i put the ` @Configurable.`before class

Comment: you need an extra config in your Spring XML config I've updated the answer

Comment: In that case you most likely missing context:component-scan pointing at this class for the @Autowired to be registered?

Answer (score 0):

You can enable Spring AOP with `@EnableSpringConfigured` and annotate your class with `@Configurable`. This let spring manage instances which are created outside the spring context with `new`. You will also need to enable either [load-time weaving](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-aj-ltw) or compile-time weaving. This is documented in [**9.8.1 Using AspectJ to dependency inject domain objects with Spring**](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-atconfigurable).

```
@Configuration
@EnableSpringConfigured
public class AppConfig {

}
```

---

```
@Configurable
public class MigificSessionListener implements HttpSessionListener {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("notificationThread")
    private NotificationThread notificationThread;

    //...

}
```